# Can't get values from deep ArrayList in Java

Tags: java, arraylist

I am try to store and get numbers in an ArrayList i have. I have this in my class:

```
private ArrayList<ArrayList> possibleNumbers = new ArrayList<ArrayList>();
```

Then i fill it with empty array lists to make sure there is something in it for each y

```
for( int x = 0; x < grid[ y ].length; x++ )
{
    possibleNumbers.get( y ).add( x , new ArrayList<Integer>());
}
```

Now far later in my code i have an ArrayList with a couple of numbers in the variable 'list', is set that list to possible numbers:

```
possibleNumbers.get( y ).set( x, list );
```

Later i try to get the value from the inserted list:

```
possibleNumbers.get( y ).get( x ).get( 0 );
```

But now i get an error:

```
symbol  : method get(int)
location: class java.lang.Object
possibleNumbers.get( y ).get( x ).get(0);
                                 ^
```

I really can't find why this third get doesn't work but the second does... I hope someone can help me.

Thanks,

Chris

Comment: Can you describe more precise what possibleNumbers should be/contain? I am not sure, your datastructure fits your needs. "store and get numbers in an ArrayList" would result in ArrayList<Number>...

Answer (score 2):

I assume that `possibleNumbers` is of type `ArrayList<ArrayList<Object>>`. And so, the object returned from `possibleNumbers.get( y ).get( x )` is considered to be an `Object`. What occurs if you cast it?

Comment: Thanks you made me realize the problem i used
private ArrayList<ArrayList<ArrayList>> possibleNumbers = new ArrayList<ArrayList<ArrayList>>();
now although its ugly, it totally works!!

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that you are trying to go three levels deeps into a two-level structure:

```
possibleNumbers.get( y ).get( x ).get( 0 )
```

- `possibleNumbers` is an `ArrayList<ArrayList<Object>>`
- `possibleNumbers.get(y)` is an `ArrayList<Object>`
- `possibleNumbers.get(y).get(x)` is an `Object`

You can't call `get(0)` on an `Object`.

Comment: What's with the bizarre downvotes lately? This is a perfect, well-formed answer. +1 for compensation.

Comment: The downvote is because it is a tree-level structure (and the initial answer only contained the first sentence, witch in my opinion is wrong. Conceptually it is a tree-level structure)

Comment: Kind of annoying that we can't figure out who does this. Time to contact admins? It seems to have become a plague.

Comment: @bruno It could be a million-level structure for all we know, because the Object in the inner list could be anything. Who cares? aix was talking about the list structure, which is two levels.

Comment: @G_H please what's happens if you to knows this person, same nothing as you never don't know that, simple ignore that,

Comment: @mKorbel Em... Sorry, but I can't really make heads or tails of what you're saying.

Answer (score 0):

You have a list that contains lists:

```
possibleNumbers //ArrayList<ArrayList>
```

The first get is going to return one of those lists:

```
posibleNumbers.get(y) //-> ArrayList
```

The second get is going to get one entry of that list:

```
possibleNumbers.get(y).get(x) //-> list entry
```

So that final `get(0)` is one too many.